# Why use std::next instead of adding an integer to the pointer?

Tags: c++, pointers, c++11

I just have a quick question. I can't figure out the benefits of using `std::next` over just adding the desired number of advancements to the pointer. A simple example:

```
 int main()
 {
     int arr [] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
     cout << *(arr + 2) << ", ";    //example 1
     cout << *std::next(arr, 2) << endl;    //example 2
     return 0;
 }
```

Output: `3, 3`

Logically, example 1 should be quicker, since no function is called, etc. Also, in the instance in which I ran this code, if I added a number that would cause the pointer to be out of bounds (e.g. 7), the compiler would throw an error in example 1, but would happily go ahead and give me a memory address in example 2. This contradicted what I thought at first: that `std::next` would give some kind of warning or something if the pointer was out of bounds.

Any enlightenment would be appreciated.

Comment: That's like saying:"why are we using Vectors instead of arrays?".`std::next` works with all iterator types, Not just raw pointers.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Because `std::next` is designed not only to work on raw pointers but on all iterators, therefore it's more versatile.

Your assumption is also false. Both approaches will most likely result in the same assembly when using reasonable optimization level. Again, c++ is designed to make such optimizations easier. In your example the underlying iterator type is a raw pointer, obviously, and it is quite trivial to deduce that the function call can be inlined.

*EDIT:*

As Matt said in his comment, there are more to iterators than just a fancy name and a template wrapper. There are data structures (containers) which do not reside in a contiguous memory segment (e.g. a `map` or `set`) they need to use more logic, to figure out the exact placement in memory. Iterators also wrap this, they provide a level of abstraction between algorithms and container.

So summing above points, using standard idioms helps in writing more robust code, i.e. supporting different types of containers (not caring about their memory layout) while keeping efficiency where possible due to quite smart compilers.

Comment: Particularly, iterators which don't support random access and therefore not `operator+` with integers.

Comment: Why would the first example throw an error, and the second one not? I'm using VC++ 2013. Specifically it says "uninitialized local variable 'arr' used".

Comment: @MattMcNabb I agree, after your comment, I decided it's worth to elaborate a bit about it. Hope it doesn't blur the picture.

Comment: @KonradKapp You are not guaranteed to get an error when going over bound of an array, in neither of your cases. It invokes undefined behaviour, so it might depend on optimization flags, system, compiler, or creativity of programmers.

Comment: @KonradKapp Btw, I urge you to read about [`array`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) methods `at` and `operator[]`. They differ precisely in what you talk about.

Comment: @luk32 yes I did read a little on it just now. Interesting. Many thanks!

Comment: ＠luk32. Just in case there is any confusion: std::array is an addition to c++11 standard library that provides fixed sized arrays. The native c/c++ arrays are different beasts altogether, and are not classes with methods.

Answer (score 13):

`std::next` works with all iterator types. If you know you're dealing with an array, adding the value works fine. However, if you're writing a generic function that you want to work on different kinds of iterators, that poses a problem.

```
iter + 5
```

That operation is only defined for random access iterators.

```
std::next(iter, 5)
```

However, that operation is defined for forward iterators, which is a much broader category of iterator. In short, `std::next` makes your code more generalized.

cplusplus.com has a full list of the operators supported by various iterator types, available [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iterator/). As the chart on that page shows, all random access iterators are also forward but not nearly all forward iterators are random access. Things like linked lists will only work with `std::next`

Comment: Just to add a little, `std::next` is not just one implementation of "apply `++` 5 times to `iter`", but is smart enough to do the more efficient thing with random access iterators, and use the "slower" increment 5 times for forward iterators (that can't just jump 5 positions).

Comment: Also worth noting that "although the expression `++c.begin()` often compiles, it is not guaranteed to do so: `c.begin()` is an rvalue [...]" (from https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/next)